# How to send a new screenshot HTML5 Canvas image to a new tab using a Google Chrome Extension?

Tags: javascript, canvas, google-chrome-extension

If you are familiar with Google Chrome Extension development you might know that Chrome extensions have an API which can be called from a `background.js` script to generate a Screenshot image of the current tab/window.

My extension creates and opens a file `editor.html` into a new tab after I generate a full-page screenshot image.

At this stage, my screenshot image is an HTML5 Canvas element inside the `background.js, background.html` context.

This same `background.js` script is what creates and opens the new `editor.html` tab.

So my question is.  What are the ways that I can pass my Canvas image to my new tab with `editor.html`?

One technique I have tried is to make my Canvas image into a Blog and save it as a temporary image which gives it a URL in the extensions to access the image file.

A second technique might be to convert the Canvas image with `canvas.toDataURL("image/png");` and send it in a `message` from `background.js` to my `editor.html` tab which has its own JavaScript files loaded into the page.  My concern here is that sometimes the image can be so large that I believe it is too large to use `toDataURL()`

So is there any other way to do this?  If not, is there a preferred way/best practice way to do this?

Comment: are you able to pass objects between tabs.  If so you can pass the context data from tab A to tab B and render it into a canvas -- http://www.w3schools.com/tags/canvas_getimagedata.asp

Comment: @QBM5 I am not sure, will have to try and test it.  As far as I know the only way to pass anything is through the Chrome Extension Messaging API.  So if I can pass the object you mention in this message that would be ideal

Comment: If you are creating a new tab from an existing tab you can keep track of the child property and pass objects via function calls, no extension needed

Answer (score 1):

> One technique I have tried is to make my Canvas image into a Blo[b] and
>   save it as a temporary image which gives it a URL in the extensions to
>   access the image file.

As long as the `objectURL` created from `Blob` is not revoked, and the browser is not closed, the `objectURL` should be available at other tabs.

For example, `url` should display `123` if opened in separate tab

```
var blob = new Blob([123]);
var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
```

---

Another approach could utilize `requestFileSystem`